# Why does the below code have a syntax error?

Tags: python

Alright, so this could turn out to be the dumbest question I've ever asked in my life, or it could turn out that there is some bug with Google Colab.
I have written the following code within IPython notebook in Google Colab, and it is throwing a syntax error with the outer `else`. Can someone please let me know where am I erring?

```
A = [5, 12, 7, 9, 2, 23, 16, 18, 24]

x=0
sum = A[0]

for num in range(1, len(A)):
  if sum == 41:
    print (A[x:num+1])
    break
  print ("num = ", num)
  sum = sum + A[num]
  print ("sum added, = ", sum)

  else:
    if sum < 41:
      print ("nested if ent")
      continue


    else:
      while sum > 41:
        print ("while entered")
        sum = sum - A[x]
        print ("sum = ", sum)
        x = x + 1
        print ("x = ", x)
```

The full error message is as follows:

```
File "<ipython-input-57-3da2751ffcdf>", line 14
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I simply can't understand what is wrong with the outer `else` (the upper one). Is it that I'm missing something obvious, in which case, please be gentle on me guys. Haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else:` isn't paired with any `if:`. I'd just get rid of it and unindent the lines below it.

```
for num in range(1, len(A)):
  if sum == 41:
    print (A[x:num+1])
    break
  print ("num = ", num)
  sum = sum + A[num]
  print ("sum added, = ", sum)

  if sum < 41:
    print ("nested if ent")
    continue
  else:
    while sum > 41:
      print ("while entered")
      sum = sum - A[x]
      print ("sum = ", sum)
      x = x + 1
      print ("x = ", x)
```

Comment: @John Kugelman Crap!! I see now, how can I be so dumb. Initially I had a totally different block of statements within the first "if" statement, and then I changed them, but I forgot to change the "else" part. Thnx for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the indentation of the 3 lines after outer if:

```
A = [5, 12, 7, 9, 2, 23, 16, 18, 24]

x=0
sum = A[0]

for num in range(1, len(A)):
    if sum == 41:
        print (A[x:num+1])
        break
        print ("num = ", num)
        sum = sum + A[num]
        print ("sum added, = ", sum)
    else:   
        if sum < 41:
          print ("nested if ent")
          continue
        else:
          while sum > 41:
            print ("while entered")
            sum = sum - A[x]
            print ("sum = ", sum)
            x = x + 1
            print ("x = ", x)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right fix. The `break` statement will prevent those lines from running.

Comment: The point is they are not considered as the body of the if and even with the break, they will be compiled and cause the error

Comment: This code does a thing, but almost certainly not the thing the questioner wanted, because of the `break`. There's more going on than bad indentation. I don't think the questioner really understood how `else` works.

Comment: @amiralisabzehparvar I'm afraid that's not the case, because I want those 3 statements precisely out of the "if" statement.